# How to express the property "spiraling around" in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

I am starting to learn differential geometry, and reading the book "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces" of Manfredo. The I got stuck on this problem:

> > Let $\alpha(t) = (ae^{bt}\cos(t), ae^{bt}\sin(t)), t\in R$, $a$ and $b$ constants, $a \gt 0, b \lt 0$, be a parametrized curve. Show that as $t \rightarrow + \infty$, $\alpha(t)$ approaches the origin 0, spiraling around it(because of this, the trace of $\alpha$ is called the logarithmic spiral)

So I can prove that $\alpha(t)$ approaches the origin 0 without any difficulty. But my question is the second part, "spiraling around". I don't know how we can express this property in term of formal expression. Can anyone give me some hint, I really appreciate.

(Sorry, I don't know how to draw a picture for you here so you can imagine it easier)

Comment: I'm not aware of any universal definition of "spiraling around" a point $p$, but a reasonable heuristic is "the curve crosses each (geodesic) ray from $p$ infinitely many times, with the same orientation at each crossing".

Comment: Sorry for being ignorant, but what do you mean by "the same orientation". Does it mean that the slope of all the tangents of intersection are the same? If so, I think I can prove it now...

Comment: "Same orientation" means, loosely, "always winding clockwise or always winding counterclockwise". :) The idea was to exclude curves such as $$\alpha(t) = \bigl(e^{-1/t}\cos[2\pi\sin(1/t)], e^{-1/t} \sin[2\pi\sin(1/t)]\bigr),\qquad 0 < t < \infty,$$say, that cross each ray infinitely many times but don't "wind around in the same direction".

Comment: Oh, I see. So how can we prove "same orientation"? I think about proving the inner product $\alpha'(t_1) \times \alpha'(t_2) \ge 0$ of all arbitrary 2 intersection points, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Remember, this entire discussion hinges on a non-standard definition I proposed; it's unlikely Do Carmo wanted any lengthy computation or geometric argument. :) That said, if you show that the "scalar cross product" $(1, 0) \times \alpha'(t)$ has the same sign at each $t$ for which $\alpha(t)$ lies on the positive $x$-axis, you've shown $\alpha$ "crosses the positive $x$-axis in the same direction at each crossing".

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot, @AndrewD.Hwang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a continuous curve $c:[a,b]\to \bf R^2 = \bf C$ do not meet the origin, you can count the number of turns it make around the origin as follows.

One knows (it is not easy to prove but this is true) that there exists a continuous function $\theta (t)$ such that $c(t)= \rho (t) \exp i \theta(t)$, where $\rho (t)= d(c(t), O)$ is the distance to the origin.The function $\theta$ is not unique but defined modulo a constant (a multiple of $2\pi$). The total variation of angle $\theta (b) -\theta (a)$ is well defined, and one see that the curve make $[{\theta (b) -\theta (a) \over 2 \pi}]$ turns around the origin, plus a certain remaining angle.

In your case, $\theta (t)=t$ so in fact at the time $t$, your curve made $n$ turns around the origin  if $t\in [n2\pi, (n+1)2\pi[$.